# how to add static in LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have an issue with LINQ query...

I am retriving data in list

```
 public List<Station_Master> GetAllStations()
    {
        var stationlist = from s in dc.Station_Masters
                          select s;
        return stationlist.ToList();

    }
```

But here my table Station_Masters contains One Status field as Data Type int..

List will give me all records from table including status...

But I need to show Status as String ...

I mean if Status is 0 then it will return "active" or if it is  1 then it will return "Inactive"

How can I do this with this ?

Comment: Create a read only property "StatusString" in Station_Master. The the @James answer below.

Comment: Adding a string status to anything in your data model is almost certainly a wrong thing to do if all you need is to display the status differently: this is not an appropriate layer for that. Interpretation of the active/inactive status should be left up to your display layer.

Comment: @devundef ... how can I use that property ?

Answer (score 7):

There are quite a number of ways you could do this, one example could be to extend the `Station_Master` class to expose a property that will return you the string representation of the status:

```
public partial class Station_Master
{
    public string StatusText
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Status)
            {
                case 0:
                    return "Active";
                case 1:
                    return "Inactive";
                default:
                    return "Unknown";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 good point - it's always better to separate data issues from presentation

Comment: This is also a valid alternative to my solution if you can extend the original class

Comment: @MatteoMosca This solution is more effecient as there is no need to create any sort of DTO, the OP's code would work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DTO where the Status is a string and not an integer, and leave all other properties as the original object.

Then your method can simply:

```
return dc.Station_Masters
.Select(c => new CustomObject
{
//Map all other fields and then remap the status
Status = c.Status == 0 ? "Active" : "Inactive"
});
```

This is however inefficient as if would extract all the rows from the table in order to remap them. You'd better apply the `Select` transformation only after filtering them.

Comment: is this  query will return all column records including status ?

Comment: Yes but you need to remap manually all the properties you need using the select statement. I omitted them for simplicity's sake. The best thing you can do as I stated is filter the data as you need and then use the select statement to make a projection in a new form, trnasforming the Status column and maybe other columns if you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to keep "active/inactive" description away from data-retrieval logic.
As @James suggested - just extend your class and explicitly compile description property.